# Setting form target to _blank causes 2 windows to open

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using the following script with a Paypal button, which works well, except for the fact that 2 windows open to Paypal, instead of one. I would appreciate if anyone could help me get just 1 window to open. This is inside of an asp.net project. There is one form in the source on the page.

```
function submitFormToPaypal() {
    var formElementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');

    if (formElementsArray != null) {
        var formElement = formElementsArray[0];

        document.getElementById('__VIEWSTATE').name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';

        formElement.action = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        formElement.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        formElement.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this formElement.setAttribute("target", "_blank") and test. Let us know the behavior.

Comment: It opens no pop ups, but changes the page. I'm looking for the page not to change, and one pop up. Thanks.

Comment: If you call your function on submit or on click of a submit button, you need to remove the formelement.submit. Please show the HTML and event handlers of the form

Comment: That was the problem, thank you very much mplungjan.

Answer (score 0):

If you call your function on submit or on click of a submit button, you need to remove the formelement.submit.

If you show the HTML with event handlers perhaps we can suggest how to do it.